# How to train a single channel( grayscale image) model on yolov7?

Tags: pytorch, yolo

My image resolution is 1440x1080x1(grayscale), I don't want to resize it because there are some small objects in the image. How can I modify the yaml file so that yolov7 can train on single channel images? The "image_size" in "train.py" means to [train, test] ,not [width, height], and I have not found a place to modify the channel and train input size

yolov7 official demo:https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7

Comment: please add the code or at least the link to the repository that you used for yolov7.

Comment: yolo models receive rgb as an input, you will have to resize and the channel you can just convert it as so, small objects can be handle with anchors, please look on the topic anchors https://blog.roboflow.com/what-is-an-anchor-box/

Comment: another option is a more heavier object detector such as detr

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert a single-channel grayscale image into an "RGB" image: simply copying the channel three times.

Comment: Or by adding a conv layer with (input_channel=1, output_channel=3).
So yolov7 will be getting an input after being passed by this conv layer.

Comment: @AhmadAnis this will entail retraining of the entire model. In that scenario, it is better to replace the first layer with a conv that expects only a single channel. Alternatively, you can modify the **trained** weights of the first layer to replicate the input channel -- I'll leave it as an exercise on how to do that.

Comment: Won't the entire model be trained anyways? The difference would be that the first layer would be intialized randomly and yolov7 would be intialized via coco.

Comment: @AhmadAnis this depends on the user - if s/he wants to retrain. My solution is for using the same model **as-is** for grayscale images.

Comment: Alright. Because training was in the title, so that's why i suggested it.